# What's with this edit and how do I categorize it?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

This suggested edit appears to be completely bogus, perhaps an attempt to farm reputation.  I'm not sure how to categorize it, however--didn't quite fit the description of vandalism, so I labeled it as incorrect.  Perhaps vandalism would have been a better fit though; it really messed up the question.  Here's the link:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5649293

Comment: If something "really messed up the question" why would you not categorise it as vandalism?

Comment: Didn't quite fit the provided definition of vandalism, which seemed more like "something abusive, offensive, or spam"...

Comment: I'm pretty sure adding gibberish to a post counts as vandalism.

Comment: This is a test edit - it is one of those that you should mark as 'invalid'. You'll get a congratulatory message saying that it was a test to see if you were paying attention.

Comment: It also says "defaces the post in some way", which is the definition of vandalism. If someone adds nonsense to a question don't be afraid to call it how it is.

Comment: Also, happy couch buying execute the maximal effects on coronal tv bargains yes pony.

Comment: Haha, alright.  Glad I passed the test (well, perhaps would have received more credit for filling in the vandalism bubble).

Comment: These edit review queue audits will start to look very familiar once you've seen a bunch of them. I can mostly recognize them based on the diff color pattern before I even start reading the random words. I started using "Vandalism" for them, but "Invalid Edit" seems fine as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This suggested edit appears to be completely bogus

Right, because it *is* complete bogus. It was a review audit consisting of randomly generated text meant to ensure you are paying attention.

A perfect reason to use is the invalid edit reason because, well, it's invalid (and that's the reason I always use for audits). What more is there to say about it? All in all, it doesn't really matter what reason you select because the reason doesn't actually get recorded onto the audit itself.

Comment: @iStimple That's because people like to ignore the word "or" in that sentence. It's meant to classify "an attempt to comment" as an invalid edit, not the other way around.